# An error in my singleton method, when create an instance. I want one instance only

Tags: php, singleton, instance

I have the Register class below to create an instance and save it into array.

```
// The register class
class Register {

    private static $objects = array();
    private function __construct() {}

    private function __clone() {}

    public static function Singleton($class) {
        if (in_array($class, self::$objects)) {
            return self::$objects[$class];
        }
        return self::$objects[$class] = new $class();
        }
}

// Example
class examp {
    public static function Singleton() {
        return Register::Singleton(get_class());
    }

    public function message() {
        echo "Hello";
    }
}

$var = examp::Singleton();
$var2 = examp::Singleton();

// I'm using that way to make sure, but tell me false
if($var === $var2){
   echo "Yes";
} else {
   echo "No";
}
```

When I make sure if $var get the same instance of $var2, tell me false or no.
I want to know why $var and $var2 not get the same instance, what the problem in my Register class ?

Comment: `in_array($class, self::$objects)` seem not to work

Comment: I see you deleted your question about restricting access to files on a web server. I don't generally recommend that people do that, since it is an inconvenience to the people who have answered, and who are in the middle of answering.

Comment: Here was my comment: _This isn't very clear, but I think I've worked it out. If a file is read by a browser, it should be prevented from being read, but if it is read programmatically, it should be permitted? Well, you could look at the user agent string, but that can be faked. Can you give more detail about what you are trying to achieve? Maybe it can be done a better (more secure) way._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check if there is a value but you should check key instead.

You should not use [in_array()](https://www.php.net/in_array) function use [array_key_exists()](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists) instead.

From **PHP** manual:

- [in_array](https://www.php.net/in_array) — Checks if a value exists in an array
- [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists) — Checks if the given key or index exists in the array

change

```
if (in_array($class, self::$objects)) {
```

to

```
 if (array_key_exists($class, self::$objects)) {
```

[Working demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qMsX0l)